# How to solve exception: "Call was rejected by callee. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))"?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`namespace.

The `Document.SaveAs2` method does not accept the path given as first parameter.

```cs
if (saveFileDialog_Docx.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    string originalPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string dirpath = Path.Combine(originalPath, saveFileDialog_Docx.FileName);
    //lbl_test.Text = dirpath;
    document.SaveAs2(@""+ dirpath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Whether I use as first argument `dirpath` or `@"" + dirpath`, the path is not accepted, and the following exception is thrown:

> Exception:Call was rejected by callee. Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))

I want to get path from `savefiledialog`.

Comment: 1. Format code, 2. add more details for the question, what you want etc. 3. until we know what is in `dirpath`, we can't tell you what to do.

Comment: May or may not fix your issue. Please [check the method signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas2?view=vsto-2017) carefully again, pay attention to your first argument :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of the method `SaveAs2` shows that the signature is:

```cs
public void SaveAs2 (
    ref object FileName,
    ref object FileFormat,
    ref object LockComments,
    [...]
    ref object CompatibilityMode);
```

It shows that `FileName` is a `ref` parameter. As such you simply need to add `ref` before your argument, as you did for the others. No need to add the `@""` before the `dirpath` variable.

Your code should be:

```cs
document.SaveAs2(ref dirpath, ref missing, [...] ref missing);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas2?view=vsto-2017

Comment: thank you .. in addition i was declarate " string dirpath  ". i change it to " object dirpath "

Comment: You should be able to pass it directly as `string`, since `string` inherits from `object`, as almost all types. You can check the doc: 
Inheritance
    Object
    String
 in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0